# reverse proxy on apache for a single virtual host

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, reverse-proxy, proxypass

**Preamble:**

I've configured a publicly accessible server with multiple virtual hosts.
The requests for one virtual host need to be sent to a backend server.
All the other requests need to be served locally.

**Problem:**

The request for ALL the virtual hosts are passed on to the IP address specified in the ProxyPass directive once the website which needs to be proxied is enabled.
When I try to visit any of the other virtual hosts I get the webpage from the proxied website. When disabling the proxied website all other virtual hosts resume normal operation and are served locally.

**Config:**

The config I have on the publicly accessible server for the virtual hosts:
(other virtual hosts are copies of the same config)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.mainsite.com
  ServerAlias mainsite.com
  ServerAdmin admin@mainsite.com

  DirectoryIndex index.php
  DocumentRoot /var/www/mainsite.com

  <Directory />
    AllowOverride None
  </Directory>

  LogLevel info
  ErrorLog /var/log/mainsite.com_err.log
  CustomLog /var/log/mainsite.com_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The config I have on the publicly accessible server for the virtual host to be proxied:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerName calendar.othersite.com
  ServerAdmin admin@othersite.com

  ProxyRequests Off 

  <Location />
    ProxyPass http://192.168.0.1/
    ProxyPassReverse http://192.168.0.1/
  </Location>

  <Proxy>
   Order Allow,Deny
   Allow from all
  </Proxy>


  TransferLog /var/log/othersite.com_access.log
  ErrorLog /var/log/othersite.com_err.log
  CustomLog /var/log/othersite.com.log combined
  LogLevel debug
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You should be able to set up a ProxyPass/Reverse line for that specific site before the general one and have it go there, Apache should read them from first to last.

Comment: I'd try to add `DocumentRoot /var/www/othersite.com`. It can be empty directory of course. It's a wild guess though - I'm just not sure if `<Location />` does not leak to other sites if it is for example `/var/www` for this vhost, inherited from main config.

Comment: @Tometzky Adding DocumentRoot did not solve the problem.

Comment: Another wild guess - remove `ProxyPassReverse` and add `ProxyPreserveHost on` instead.

Comment: @Tometzky removing ProxyPassReverse and adding ProxyPreseveHost did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/mods-available/proxy.load /etc/apache2/mods-enabled
sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/mods-available/proxy_http.load /etc/apache2/mods-enabled
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```